# Cómo solucionar el too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 45564 seconds usando la api de stackoverflow

Tags: api

Estoy usando la api de stackoverflow y realice tantas peticiones por segundo que bloqueo mi IP.

El mensaje que me sale es too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 45564 seconds

Como podría solucionar el problema??

Comment: Si usas una conexión con ip dinámica (adsl, modem 3g, etc.) podrías intentar a desconectarte de internet y volver a conectarte. Quizás así tu proveedor te asigne una nueva IP. Otra opción es utilizar un acceso a internet diferente. No conozco la api de stackoverflow, pero si va a traves de http podrías probar a utilizar un proxy público, si te fías de alguno.

Comment: No creo que haya forma de "solucionar el problema" pues es una medida de precaución que cualquier sitio toma. La duda sería qué tratas de hacer que activaste un mecanismo de defensa global.

Comment: Es que estaba probando de obtener la localizacion de todos los usuarios de stackoverflow en español. Como no hay una forma directa de obtener por pais. Estaba haciendo varias peticiones. La verdad que podria a ver reducido el tiempo y la forma pero no pense que podrian bloquear con esa cantidad

Comment: @Luis ya desconecte mi internet y sigue el mismo problema. Pensé que podría haber otra manera de desbloquear. Reportar en algún lugar o algo así. Voy a usar desde otra conexión de internet, Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si continuas realizando peticiones desde la misma IP, **debes esperar la cantidad de millisegundos descrita en el mensaje**.

Es una forma mediante la cual el sitio se protege de una cantidad de peticiones que pudieran causar problemas al servidor.

Comment: ya me funciona. Gracias